# Ejabberd MUC Set time before deletion after last member leaves for not persistent room

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I can set `muc#roomconfig_persistentroom` option during MUC room creation process.

But if I set this option to `false`, room will be deleted after last member leaves room.

I need to set living time for room after last member leaves it. So, when last member leaves room it still live for, example, 10 sec. If someone will join room during this period, room will not be deleted.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting allowing to delay MUC destruction in XMPP MUC rooms. Either the room is persistent or not. There is no such feature in MUC specification.